# ExecuteScalar valued function with parameters in c# and return messagebox

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a scalar-valued function with 2 parameters. This function checks if the content of textbox is true or false. Now I want to execute this function in the validating event of this textbox and if the result is false then return a message box, else nothing.

This is my code so far:

```
private void txtboxPromitheutisAFM_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       _con = new SqlConnection();
       _con = DBAccess.Conn;

       _con.Open();

       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT fAFMisUsedBySynalasomenoi(@AFM)", _con);
       command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AFM", txtboxPromitheutisAFM.Text));

       int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
       {
           Response.Write(String.Format("{0}", reader["PromitheutisID"]));
       }

       _con.Close();
    }
    catch { }
 }
```

This is the name of the function: `fAFMisUsedBySynalasomenoi`.

These are the parameters:

```
@AFM VARCHAR(50), @excludedSynalasomenosID INT = NULL
```

The name of the textbox: `txtboxPromitheutisAFM`

Can somebody help?

Comment: I think you mean scalar valued function. But more importantly, you haven't asked an actual question. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: What is your error or problem? BTW, you don't need to `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: i don't know how to import the second parameter and i don't know where to put the messagebox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What kind of message box are you expecting to use in a web app? If you know how to add parameter `@AFM` why don't you know how to add the other?